# Display a message upon the beginning and completion of a function in OSC API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, node-modules

The idea is to allow me to press a button on the HTML page to execute a command to copy and delete all photos on cameras with feedback showing at the beginning and ending of the execution.

**At the moment, after clicking the "Get Images From Camera", the textarea is showing this text:**

> Executed command: \copyImages
>
> Result is as below: Copying images from
> both cameras...\n

And it goes on to copy and delete all images like I want. But at the end of this process, nothing is returned back to the screen, so the user has no idea what happens. The nature of callback in Node js makes it too confusing for me to figure out how to do this.

*P.S. I've tried all I know before I come here to get your help. So know that any suggestions are very appreciated!*

**So, my question is how do I change the codes below so that I could
display a message to show the user that the copying is completed successfully like:**

> Please wait for the copying to complete...
>
> Completed!

Below are the HTML markups

```
<button id="copyImages" type="button" class="button">Get Images From Camera</button>
<textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

Here is the Javascript event handling:

```
copyImages.onclick = function() {
    dest = '/copyImages';
    writeToOutput(dest);
}
function writeToOutput(dest) {
        $.get(dest, null, function(data) {
            resultText += "Executed command: "+dest+"\n" 
                                    +"Result is as below: \n"+data;
            $("#output").val(resultText);
        }, "text");
        return true;
     }
```

*These functions below are for setting up a Node App server using express module to listen to anything the HTML page passes to it. They are run on a different device.*

```
expressServer.listen( expressPort, function() {
    console.log('expressServer listening at *:%d', expressPort );
    
});

// allow CORS on the express server
expressServer.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // enable cross original resource sharing to allow html page to access commands
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    
    // return to the console the URL that is being accesssed, leaving for clarity
    console.log("\n"+req.url);
    
    next();
});

expressServer.get('/copyImages', function (req, res) {
    // user accesses /copyImages and the copyImages function is called
    copyImages(function(result) {
        res.end(result + "\n");
    });
});
```

*Copy images from Theta S Camera to Raspberry Pi and delete those from the cameras*

```
var resultCopyImages = "";

copyImages = function (callback) {
    resultCopyImages = "Copying images from both cameras...\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < camArray.length; i++) {
        copyOneCamImages(i, callback);
    }
    return (callback(resultCopyImages));
//how to return multiple messages?
}

copyOneCamImages = function (camID, callback) {
    
    d.on('error', function(err){
        console.log('There was an error copying the images');
        return(callback('There was an error running a function, please make sure all cameras are connected and restart the server'));
    })
    
    d.run(function(){
        
        var imageFolder = baseImageFolder + camID;
        // if the directory does not exist, make it
        if (!fs.existsSync(imageFolder)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(imageFolder);
            console.log("no 'images' folder found, so a new one has been created!");
        }

        // initialise total images, approximate time
        var totalImages = 0;
        var approxTime = 0;

        // get the first image and do not include thumbnail
        var entryCount = 1;
        var includeThumb = false;
        var filename;
        var fileuri;

        // get the total amount of images
        camArray[camID].oscClient.listImages(entryCount, includeThumb)
            .then(function (res) {
            totalImages = res.results.totalEntries;
            approxTime = totalImages * 5;
            resultCopyImages = '';
            resultCopyImages = 'Camera ' + (camID + 1) + ': Copying a total of: ' + totalImages + ' images'
                + '\nTo folder: ' + imageFolder
                + '\nThis process will take approximately: ' + approxTime + ' seconds \n';
            console.log(resultCopyImages);
            callback(resultCopyImages);
            });

        // copy a single image, with the same name and put it in images folder
        camArray[camID].oscClient.listImages(entryCount, includeThumb)
            .then(function (res) {
            filename = imageFolder + '/' + res.results.entries[0].name;
            fileuri = res.results.entries[0].uri;
            imagesLeft = res.results.totalEntries;

            // gets the image data
            camArray[camID].oscClient.getImage(res.results.entries[0].uri)
                .then(function (res) {

                var imgData = res;
                fs.writeFile(filename, imgData);
                camArray[camID].oscClient.delete(fileuri).then(function () {
                    if (imagesLeft != 0) {
                        // callback to itself to continue copying if images are left
                        callback(copyOneCamImages(camID, callback));
        
        //????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        //if(imagesLeft==1) return(callback("Finished copying"));
                    }/* else {
        resultCopyImages = "Finshed copying image.\n";
        console.log(resultCopyImages);
        }
          else if   
                        return(callback(resultCopyImages));
                    }*/
                    });
                });
        });
    })
    
 }
```

Comment: Hi where did you display the image? Container HTML where the images from the camera beeing showing?

Comment: @headmax, I don't display them. Just copy them to a device and delete them off cameras. I want to display a msgs at the completion of the task though.

Comment: OSC API didn't explain how you did it withtout screen displaying images to ex: a canvas and then take a screenshot from there but in your case you listen on port and take data without knowing wich header type mime is used how the packets is, sorry didn't got experience on this API any npm installed?

Comment: @headmax, sure. Please refer to this [Github repo](https://github.com/mdainebir/PXGroupTen)

Comment: i show the repository, you need to drive to the forked peoples who got more contributors for this projet i guess this situation was explain with more example "i hope" https://github.com/mdainebir/PXGroupTen/graphs/contributors here about the contributor kenricnguyen https://github.com/kenricnguyen/PXGroupTen (last update 2 months ago)

Comment: I am not sure what you meant but I'm one of the contributors.

Comment: I said just run around Git and looking for all forked project to find if someone got a project more advanced than the original. I will try this project if i got time and try.

Comment: @user8556290, thanks for trying to help. We've concluded the project anyway and ended up skipping the feature. That would be for future developments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far there is no real answer to the question I asked so we have concluded the project and skipped the feature. However, it's just the matter of mastering the REST API and the asynchronous functions in NodeJs. The project is expected to continue for a next version sometime next year.